# Visual Studio not addin custom user control to toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, wpf-controls

I created a new C# WPF app project in visual studio 2017 and added a user control to the project.  Now when I try to add that user control to my main window it doesnt show up in the toolbox.

Ive checked the AutoToolboxPopulate property and it is set to true and Ive rebuilt.  Ive tried closing and opening the project and Visual Studio.

What do I need to do to get my controls to show up in the toolbox?

Comment: Did you compile the project?

Comment: Yes as I said, Ive rebuilt it.  Ive done that multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally made a normal user control instead of a WPF user control.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add it to the toolbox manually
In the toolbox, select the WPF Components. At this time, click Browse, find the dll, add it, and click OK.